# Inamp to Measure LiFePO4 Battery Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, battery-charging, measurement, instrumentation, lifepo4

I know there are a few posts regarding the best way to measure battery voltage but I didn't see any that were focused on the most precise method possible. I am designing a battery analyzer to measure battery state of health and state of charge. The general system diagram is in the picture attached. This diagram shows 1 channel of an 8 channel system. [image]

I have heard the most precise method would be to use an instrumentation amplifier to measure the voltage difference which also has the benefit of reducing required MCU inputs. Since I don't have much experience applying op-amps in design much less in-amps, I am not really sure if you can use it this way. From what I have read, they are normally used for amplifying small signals accurately and rejecting common-mode signal. The one I have selected seems to offer a unity gain option and also says it can be used as a difference amplifier, however.

My question is, can I use this in-amp (MCP6N11) to measure a 2-4V battery voltage? The typical application circuit in the datasheet (see attached) shows a very similar configuration only it is measure a small voltage across a current sense resistor instead of the battery voltage.

Due to the high input impedance of the amp, will there by any issue with antenna effect if the battery is connected to the pcb via 3-6 inch wires? If so, would switching the battery+ terminal to a 10k resistor to ground during ADC measurement reduce this effect?

Also, would the high charge/discharge current (up to 1A) affect the voltage measurement? What is the optimal way of probing the battery voltage (i.e trace width/length, location, etc).

I am hoping to achieve around .1-1mV accuracy.
[image]

Comment: do you want  most precise method possible or is 0.1mv good enough?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit contradictory there. .1mV is good enough